# Github authorization in Xcode

Tags: xcode, github, authorization

I'm running Xcode 12 developing a macOS command line tool. When I commit to GitHub I get an email saying:

> Basic authentication using a password to the API is deprecated and
> will soon no longer work. Visit
> https://developer.github.com/changes/2020-02-14-deprecating-password-auth/
> for more  information around suggested workarounds and removal dates.

I understand it's because I'm using basic authorization with username/password which GitHub is deprecating, but I cannot work out how to fix it inside Xcode. Does anyone out there know?

Comment: Does [this entry from the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#Documentation/gitfaq.txt-HowdoIchangethepasswordortokenI8217vesavedinmycredentialmanager) help?

Answer (score 0):

You have to sign in to GitHub and [create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token). Use that token to sign in to your GitHub account from Xcode. Adding the GitHub account from Xcode's Accounts preferences will let you enter a username and personal access token.

I'm surprised Xcode doesn't prompt you to enter a personal access token. Xcode wouldn't let me push to GitHub until I created a personal access token and signed in with it.